# How to automate build file deletion with CMake and Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, cmake, eclipse-cdt, rebuild

I use Eclipse CDT in combination with CMake and successfully followed the setup instructions detailed [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake%3aEclipse_UNIX_Tutorial). I use a custom make target to invoke CMake from within Eclipse ("Creating A Make Target To Run CMake"). It performs an out-of-source build inside a subdirectory of my source directory.

Sometimes I want CMake to rebuild everything and therefore delete all the contents of my build directory to force CMake to rebuild its cache etc.

At the moment I am using the project view to delete all the files in the subdirectory, but that is tedious and I want to automate it.

I tried to make another custom make target with `rm -rf ./Build/*` as the command, but that didn't work. It executed without errors but did not delete any files whatsoever.

How can I delete all files in the build subdirectory (or at least force CMake to rebuild its cache etc) by pressing a single button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a simple shell script `refresh-cmake.sh` with the following contents

```
#!bin/bash    
rm -rf build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

Just call it with `./refresh-cmake.sh` from inside your project directory and you should be all set. For single-click, use a file browser and click (or double-click) the shell script's icon.

Comment: @jotep great to have been of help